# Should a feature be made available as a toggle button (related: Feature Flags)?

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns, ux-field, features

I'm designing a new feature.

It's been proposed that we make this feature a toggle that the merchant can turn on/off at their discretion.

I’m curious to know if features should be made as a toggle.

Answer (score 1):

[Feature toggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle) or feature flags are a common way to roll out new features in an agile continuous delivery environment. They allow the feature to be used in real time by real customers in the production environment without forcing all users to adopt the new feature. Advantages include:

- Quick user feedback; some do A/B testing with feature toggles
- Giving users control over their experience (they can always use the old experience if they don't like the new one)
- If users turn off the toggle, you can follow up and ask why they don't want to use the new feature, which can potentially identify major issues
- It provides a more elegant way to manage major changes to the user's experience

Though it's called a "toggle", you don't have to literally use a toggle button to control it. (Some products do.) Regardless of how you control the switching, it's a good practice to make it easy for the user to find their way back to the old experience until you decide to cut over permanently.